# Get Carrier name (Cellular Mobile Operator name) using Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I want to get the carrier name for a Windows Phone 8.1 application.
In Windows Phone 8 (Silverlight) I used to be able to get it using

```
string CarrierName = DeviceNetworkInformation.CellularMobileOperator;
```

but this method is no longer available in Windows Phone 8.1 (Runtime). Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same problem recently.
The following code will give you the Carrier name but only if you have your data connection enabled. I coulnd't figure out another way.

```
var result = NetworkInformation.GetConnectionProfiles();
foreach (var connectionProfile in result)
{
    if (connectionProfile.IsWwanConnectionProfile)
    {
        foreach (var networkName in connectionProfile.GetNetworkNames())
        {
            ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["carrier"] = networkName;
            return networkName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost a year later... but I can't get the name this way.  I get "Unknown" on my AT&T phone.  It finds the WWAN connection profile, but has no useful info in it.  This is really a pain.